# How to parse a JSON which contains an array with only square brackets using Gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

This is my JSON response:

```
{
    "email":[
        "This field must be unique."
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of json object `email` and display it. I tried using Gson but always getting `null`. Created a model class with `email` variable with type `JSONArray` -- still no luck.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It's not even a valid json !

Comment: `JSONArray` is not a part of the Gson realm. Use either `com.google.gson.JsonArray`, `List<String>` or `String[]`.

Comment: There was a "smart" or "curly" quotation mark at the end of the JSON in your original unedited question. (That was lost in an edit.) Was that the real JSON response? Both quotation marks should be of the "dumb" or "straight" type. (And people making edits shouldn't _assume_ anything, such as valid JSON in a question about not being able to parse JSON.)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen No, I do believe it was a typo while posting the question. Having the "quotation" mark would cause: `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 41 path $.email[0]`, and the OP is claiming to have `null` rather than a parsing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `email` attribute is actually an array of strings.

The object to be deserialized by Gson should look like the following:

```
public class Response {

  @SerializedName("email")
  public List<String> emails;

}
```

Then using gson

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

And then you can access to that object by doing

```
response.emails.get(0)
```